# Visual C++, no references trying to add .dll

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll

I created a simple .dll and I am trying to use it in a simple test project. However, when I try to add a reference there are none to choose from and there is no "Browse" option.

I have some suspicion this might have something to do with my PATH as when I was installing CMake (a dependency for an unrelated non-visual studio project) CMake decided to delete EVERYTHING in my PATH.

see my screenshot: http://jsfiddle.net/t84BS/
(data-uri may not show in IE)

I image that I should be seeing some .NET references in there at least.

Comment: I think you're mixing up a bit using DLLs in .NET projects and in native C++ ones.

Comment: You are probably right, I reall just want to add my DLL, but I thought that because I don't see ANY references that something is messed up. I am following an MSDN walkthrough (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235636(v=vs.80).aspx) and got stuck on the step that explains how to add a reference to the dll

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you should be seeing in your IDE. Do you have a .def file? To get all the exported symbols from a dll run `dumpbin /EXPORTS my.dll`

In regards to the PATH variable run `for %G in ("%path:;=" "%") do @echo %G` to see each path on a separate line.

To add new paths type `PATH=%PATH%;C:\My\New\Path`

Maybe all the paths are getting set than overwritten somewhere. check your autoexec.bat Finally just reinstall Visual Studio.

Comment: My path only has 2 entires, the one for CMake, and one for system 32 that I added after realizing that CMake wiped out everything in my PATH: "C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake 2.8\bin"
"C:\WINDOWS\System32"

Answer (score 1):

In native C++, you don't add DLLs as references. You need to include the header and link against a LIB or DEF file created from the DLL.

First, you need to include the headers providing the code you need. Make sure that any DLL functions are marked as `__declspec(dllimport)` here (they should be dllexport when building the DLL itself, dllimport when using it). This may take a define at the top of the file or something. One common method is:

```
#ifdef IMPORT_MY_LIB
#    define MY_LIB_API __declspec(dllimport)
#else
#    define MY_LIB_API __declspec(dllexport)
#endif
```

Next, you need to link against the LIB. There are two methods to do this, one is vaguely more correct and one is simpler.

The correctish method is to go to project properties, in the linker settings, input section, add the library as an additional dependency (the options should look like that in VS2008 and 2010, perhaps others).

The simpler method, which I use for testing and replace with the correct one before production, is to add a:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "Library.lib")
```

directive to one of your files.

The LIB file is created when you compile your DLL, and should be used to link that DLL to others.

There is a method of linking at runtime, using the Windows API, which may be of interest later on but isn't necessary for this.